Possible to negate the effects of .fillMaxSize() for a SubcomposeLayout
I am trying to create a UI where it doens't take up the whole screen. Previously, I was able to do this by setting the height of the layout using IntrinsicSize.min. However, I now have a requirement to use a different UiModel that uses BoxWithConstraints underneath. I am now running into the following issue:
Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc. To mitigate this:

if intrinsic measurements are used to achieve 'match parent' sizing, consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured, making intrinsic measurement not needed
adding a size modifier to the component, in order to fast return the queried intrinsic measurement.

If I don't set the height of the Modifier, then the Ui takes up the whole screen instead of just the minimum required. What I have tried to get the dimensions manually, but this only works because right now there's only one UiModel I need to worry about and the dimensions are easy to get, but in the future if I need to add more then it's quite tedious to manually calculate everything and not very scalable. From my research, I understand that SubcomposeLayout defers the composition of some child components until the layout phase. Which means the intrinsic measurements are not reliably available upfront. See simplified code below.
Previously:
OriginalUiComposer.kt
@Composable
private fun ComposeUi(someUiModel: SomeUiModel, modifier: Modifier) {
  Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
    someUiComposer.compose(someUiModel, modifier)
  }
}

Current:
OriginalUiComposer.kt
@Composable
private fun ComposeUi(someUiModel: SomeUiModel, modifier: Modifier) {
  val requiredUiModel = RequiredUiModel(someUiModel)
  Row(Modifier.height(calculateHeightManually())) {
    requiredUiComposer.compose(requiredUiModel, modifier)
  }
}

@Composable
private fun calculateHeightManually(): Dp {
  // do stuff
  return 100.dp
}

RequiredUiComposer.kt
@Composable
override fun compose(requiredUiModel: RequiredUiModel, modifier: Modifier) {
  BoxWithConstraints {
    @Composable
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
      someUiComposer.compose(uiModel, modifier)
    }
  }
}

I'm wondering what is the best way for me to get dimensions such that I can set the height for the parent layout? The issue is I cannot make any changes to any of the layouts used within RequiredUiComposer.kt, the most I can do is add some helper methods. So I would most likely need to make the changes within OriginalUiComposer.kt
I'd appreciate any help on this, thanks!
EDIT: Upon some more investigating, it seems like the culprit is the .fillMaxSize() modifier in RequiredComposer.kt. I'm wondering if there's some kind of modifier that can be passed in to revert this without needing to modify the code within RequiredComposer.kt? I've updated the title of the question to be more accurate
